# Automating transcoding job on Amazon Elastic Transcoder

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Is it possible to automate transcoding job on Amazon Elastic Transcoder? I am using Django framework. If yes, how do I start. I have not come across any such topics, so I had to ask here. Your help and advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is automatable as they provide an API.

API Reference - Amazon Elastic Transcoder : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/api-reference.html

You should be able to call the APIs from anywhere, even from your Django app.

This example helps you setup a video trans-coding pipeline.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just one more question though, or an advice. I was thinking of creating an app in django where users can upload videos and it will be converted to mp4 in AMAZON Elastic Transcoder. Is it good for it, or do I think of something else?

Comment: Yes, AWS transcoder is ideal for such needs. You will have your Django app upload videos, then store in S3. Transcoder picks it, converts and puts it back in S3 again. Then your users can download from the link which you provide to them from S3.

Comment: Great!!! Thank you. Can you provide any tutorial or a starting point please? And add it in the answer too.

Comment: @SonyKadavan: Transcoder doesn't automatically pick files as soon as they're stored in a specified S3 bucket -- you need to create a job to transcode them, either via the console or REST. I had hoped it was event driven, that as soon as videos were uploaded to one S3 bucket, a job would be kicked off that would transcode them and put them in another bucket.